# Patch links in a Mach-O file?

Tags: linker, mach-o

I have a Mach-O binary which is very old and linked to a bunch of old frameworks than no longer exist or incompatible.

My aim is to abstract the components from these frameworks without replacing my existing frameworks. For that I want to change the built in frameworks paths so they point to my abstracted frameworks.

**How can I modify the paths of linked frameworks in a Mach-O file?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mac OS X has a program called [install_name_tool](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/install_name_tool/osx-10.6.php) for this task.

The `-change` option is what you are probably looking for:

```
install_name_tool -change oldLibName yourNewImplmentation machOFile
```